# How I can store $10 value in MYSQL getting value from oledb

Tags: mysql, postgresql, oledb

I am getting data from postgresql by oledb. and data stored is $10 in postgresql. when i get from provider it gives 8 in double and 0.008 in currency data type, how i can get correct value $10 and store in mysql

Comment: Is the dollar sign really part of that field? If so, it's probably not a numerical but string field. The odd values of 8 and 0.008 might be the result of a type cast, or maybe the output is formatted in octal notation?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a monetary datatype, you have to use a VARCHAR (bad idea!) or split the content in 2 fields: one for the currency and one for the number.